# Tracking upload progress in itemView

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, marionette

I am developing an application with Marionette/Backbone.  The app needs to upload files over an AJAX call (have this working).  I want to give the user feedback on when they are able to select the uploaded file and proceed with modifying it.  I don't know what the best practice is for tracking the progress when I have a Model and ItemView for it.  I could put it in the attributes but as far as I know, all of the attributes will be saved into the database when it syncs to the server.  But the ItemView needs to be able to listen to the model as to when it is done, I just am unsure when and where to do that.

I already have solved a more basic solution to this, but it needs to work within the Marionette/Backbone framework.

Relevant part of ItemView

```
modelEvents: {
    'change': 'fieldsChanged'
},

fieldsChanged: function() {
    this.render();
},
```

Comment: How about adding a property to the item view? They're a one to one corrosion between the view and its model?

Comment: How about adding a property to the item view? They're a one to one corrosion between the view and its model? BTW, you can listen to when the model request begins by listening to the model's `request` event, and when it comes back by listening to its `sync` event.

Comment: Well the thing is that I do not want to save the information.  Is there a way I can ignore a field for updating or does it even matter if I set it because it will never be saved?

Comment: You can directly set a property on the model. Like, `model.progress = 'loaded'`. Invoking `model.set()` implies that you are updating the a model representation of the DB. That said, if you do go with `.set()` you could preprocess the model before you call `.save()`, and manually remove the progress prop.

Comment: What if I would like to have is a progress bar in the item view on the ajax upload.  Maybe it is my ignorance of Javascript that is preventing me.  But what I was trying to do is set a variable and when it updates, that I rerender the itemview.  Is this not the correct way to approach this?

Comment: That all depends on the context. Post your item view

Comment: I added what I think is the relevant part of the item view.

Comment: A variable will only exist scope of the method it was declared in. If you want multiple methods to have access to data you'll need to either set a property of the view (which works because Marionette binds event callbacks to the view) or the model itself. See my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may have multiple `ItemView` views, each with its own model. To track changes that occur in that view's model, it's common to preserve state information about that model. To make sure that that data is available inside your `ItemView` methods, the only way to have scope to this variable would be by making it a property of the view itself. So, in your example you'd probably do something like,

```
onClick: function (event) {
  this.progress = 'pending';
  this.model.save({ filename: this.file Name })
}
```

And when the model comes back you'd do

```
fieldChanged: function () {
  this.progress = 'loaded';
  this.render();
}
```

The only other way to store model meta data and make it available in a view's context would be via a global variable, but the drawbacks to this are twofold. On a basic level you want to a avoid polluting your global score. More problematic, is how you reference the global variable to your specific view model. You can about both issues, and be more aligned with best practice, by allowing the view to keep track of all model meta data.

Alternatively, and possibly more self-consistent, ***you can set the progress property on the model itself***. And even if the model gets passed from one view to another, the state information follows the model. And your vibe would like like this

```
onClick: function (event) {
  this.model.progress = 'pending';
  this.model.save({ filename: this.file Name })
}
```

And when the model comes back you'd do

```
fieldChanged: function () {
  this.model.progress = 'loaded';
  this.render();
}
```